# MVVM light strange action with DataGrid and Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

My things are MVVMLight for Visual studio 2017, WPF, ORM with Dapper.

I have one Simple Model

```
public class User
{
  public int userId;
  public int userName;
}
```

I have one VM

```
public class VMUserInfo:ViewModelBase

    {
      private User _userInfo;
      private ObservableCollection<User> _userInfos;
      public User UserInfo
      {
        get
        {
           return _userInfo;
        }
        set
        { 
           _useInfo = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("UserInfo");
         }
      public ObservableCollection<User> UserInfos
      {  
        get 
        {
          return _userInfos;
        }
        set
        {
          _userInfos = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("UserInfos");
        }  


      public RelayCommand<User> SelectUserCommand
      {
        get;set;
      }

      public VMUserInfo()
      {
        UserInfo = new user();
        UserInfos = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        SelectUserCommand = new RelayCommand<User>(SelectUser);
      }
      private void SelectUser(User uInfo)
      {
        if (uInfo != null)
        { 
            UserInfo = uInfo;
        }
      }

    }
```

I have a View with two text box and a datagrid.
I bind(two way) these two textboxes from VM's properties(Userinfo.UserId,UserInfo.UserName);

And I bind datagrid with VM's UserInfos Collection

My Command Binding from XML is like following

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridUsers" Grid.Row="2"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserInfos}"
                      IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  >

                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
                        <mvvm:EventToCommand CommandParameter="{Binding 
        ElementName=dataGridUsers, Path=SelectedItem}" Command="{Binding 
        SelectUserCommand, Mode=OneWay}">
                        </mvvm:EventToCommand>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

After all this, everything works fine by when I Select a row from datagrid, two textboxes are filled with selected data.

One strange thing here is when I edit the textboxes, ROW FROM DATAGRID also updated.
This gave me headache and I can finally solve it changing my Command's method.

```
private void SelectUser(User uInfo)
          {
            if (uInfo != null)
            { 
                UserInfo tempUser = new User();
                tempUser.userId = uInfo.userId;
                tempUser.userName = uInfo.userName;
                UserInfo = tempUser;
            }
          }
```

Even it is solved like that I still can't figure out why this is happening.
Anyone please explain it for me. Thanks.

Comment: From what you've shown here, there are no `Userinfo.UserId` and `Userinfo.UserName` properties, and your bindings wouldn't work at all. Please try to be more precise, and show all relevant parts of your code.

Comment: This is the sample code to reproduce the process from my real project. In my project, I used Dapper to fill these properties and binding is fine. I filled the collection like -> private void LoadUsers()
        {
            _dataService.GetUsers(
                (users , error)=>
                {
                    UserInfos=users;
                }
                );
        }

Comment: Perhaps the generated(?) properties also fire the PropertyChanged event. That would easily explain why the DataGrid is updated.

Comment: That's why it is strange. Textbox binding is from single object (UserInfo), Datagrid binding is from collection. I pass selected row as object from datagrid to my single object. But when i update single object, the collection is also changed.

Comment: That's not strange at all. The single object is also an element of the collection. In other words, two object references referring to the same object.

Comment: If it is so, I can't always assign directly to my property not to update the datagrid? Whatever it is , Thanks you for your time